# hangman program, error: cannot find symbol, buffered reader? Java newbie

Tags: java

Here is the part part of my program with most of the errors:

```
    //play method
    private void play() throws IOException
    {
        do {
            guess(alphabet);
            usedLetters(used, alphabet);

            do {
                System.out.println("You have already guessed this " + alphabet + " and the others listed above.");
                guess(alphabet);
            } while (letterUsed == true);//will keep asking until letter was not used

            if (letterUsed == false)
            {
                life--;
                underWord(currentWord , checkLetter, used);
            } //only if the letter was not used, it will be checked for in the current word trying to be solved

            if (life == 0) {
                checkWord(currentWord , checkLetter);
            }
        } while (checkLetter != currentWord);

    }
```

This method in particular has all the errors at the moment. I need to ask for the user's guess of 1 alphabet, then check if it is in the word that they are currently trying to guess. I also store all the letters they have already guessed to make sure that they wont lose lives for guessing the same letter twice. So her I have three arrays, one to store the used letters, one to store the parts of the word that have been already guessed(and parts where an _ is necessary) and one that stores the word they are trying to guess. Is there a better way I could write this method below to do its required task?

```
//underWord method to return the word with all characters not in letters replaced by _'s
private void underWord(char currentWord[] , char checkLetter[], char used[]) throws IOException //add parameters what it recieves
{

    for (int i = 0; i<currentWord.length; i++) {
       for (int index = 0; index<checkLetter.length; index++){
               if (used.contains(currentWord.charAt(i)))
            {
                checkLetter[index] =  currentWord.charAt(i);
            }

            else
            {
                checkLetter[index] = '_';
            }
          }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < checkLetter.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(checkLetter[i]);
    }
}//End of maskWord method
```

I compile and the following shows:

```
C:\Users\HOME\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\twoHangman\src\twoHangman.java:289: error: cannot find symbol
               if (used.contains(currentWord.charAt(i)))
                                            ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable currentWord of type char[]

C:\Users\HOME\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\twoHangman\src\twoHangman.java:291: error: cannot find symbol
                checkLetter[index] =  currentWord.charAt(i);
                                                 ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable currentWord of type char[]

C:\Users\HOME\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\twoHangman\src\twoHangman.java:312: error: cannot find symbol
    alphabet = kb.readline().charAt(0);
                 ^
symbol:   method readline()
location: variable kb of type BufferedReader
```

It's my first time using Buffered Reader, and I am not sure what is wrong

```
//guess method to ask for user's guess

private void guess(char alphabet) throws IOException//add parameters what it recieves
{
    System.out.println("Guess a letter in this 5-letter word: ");
    alphabet = kb.readline().charAt(0);
    used[dataSize] = alphabet;
    //adds guess to used letters array

}


//usedLetters method to check if user's guess has already been guessed
private boolean usedLetters(char used[], char alphabet) throws IOException
{
    for(int x=0; x<used.length; x++)
    {
        if(alphabet == used[x])
        {
            letterUsed = true;
            return letterUsed;
        }
        else
        {
            letterUsed = false;
            return letterUsed;
        }
     }

     for (int index = 0; index < used.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(used[index]);
    }


}


//checkWord method to see if the user has got the correct word

private void checkWord(char currentWord[], char checkLetter[]) throws IOException
{
    for(int x=0; x<currentWord.length; x++)
    {
        if(checkLetter == currentWord)
        {
            System.out.println("HUZZAH! You have guessed the word!");
            System.out.println("You have completed this game of hangman.");
            menu();
        }

        System.out.println("You have run out of guesses!");
        System.out.println("The word was:");
        for (int index = 0; index < currentWord.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(currentWord[index]);
        }
        menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a huge reading assignment you've posted.... I'm going to re-format it to make it _somewhat_ more readable.

Comment: @jahroy: f**k, we should be able to vote edits up; virtual +1.

Answer (score 1):

First, `readline` should be `readLine` - Java is case sensitive.

---

More importantly, `currentWord` is a char array. To access the char at index `i`, you would use `currentWord[i]` instead of `currentWord.charAt(i)`.

Also, you can't use `used.contains(anything)` since `used` is an array. Try looping through `used` to check for a match.

Answer (score 1):

As @irrelephant has pointed out: you've spelled *readLine()* wrong.

The `L` must be capitalized.

---

The other error message is also extremely straightforward.

It's telling you that there is no such method *charAt()* for arrays.

Arrays don't have any methods in Java.

However, String **does** have a method named *charAt()*

In Java there is a difference between an array of chars and a String.

The variables *checkLetter* and *currentWord* should be Strings (not char arrays).

---

You'll be much better served to learn how to work through these errors on your own.

Coming to StackOverflow every time you get a compile error wastes both your time and ours.

Comment: I have already declared Buffered reader at the top in the class, 

import java.io.*;

public class twoHangman {

    BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

I was taught that to read in a char, I would have to use this line: char letter = kb.readLine().charAt(0);

Comment: There is no evidence that you've declared a BufferedReader in the code you've shared.  The code you've "_been taught_" to use is correct, but it will only work if your BufferedReader has been initialized properly and is accessible from the method in which you try to use it.  There is no evidence that either of these things have been done.

Comment: I recommend making your life easier and breaking down this assignment into small tasks.  First work on reading a character from a BufferedReader in a small test program.  Once you get that to work, move on to the next step.  You've written way to much code before testing.

Answer (score 1):

`currentWord` is declared as `char currentWord[]`. This means that `currentWord` is an array of `char`. In Java, this is not the same as a `String`. In particular, arrays do not have any methods. You need to use array subscripting, such as `currentWord[i]` rather than `currentWord.charAt(i)`. Alternatively, you can design your program to use `String`s rather than `char[]`.